# How to show k2 article previous date only and upcoming only

Tags: joomla-3.x, k2

I am creating k2 articles as events. There will be:

1. Upcoming events
2. Old events.

I am not able to show old events for current date. How to filter both types of events (Upcoming/Old) with single category. In k2 article filter showing all event post by date old/new, etc..

But my requirement is:

1. Upcoming event article show only
2. Old event article show only.

with a single category.

Please help me how to filter both type article.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without a 3rd party plugin, or hacking K2.

Hacking K2 is not recommended, because any modifications will be lost after updating K2.

AFAIK, no 3rd party plugin exists implementing this functionality.

So, the solution is to develop a plugin, or hire a developer if you don't know how to develop it.

Comment: can i do k2 component override  method. or third 3rd party plunging like joomla art k2 filter. my problems is i am not figure out how to work filter function.  how to write own filter function in k2  component override  method template or ja filter plugging.

Comment: It can't be done using K2 template override, this will not help. You need to know php and Joomla api to be able to write your own plugin.